# Fastest way to parse a date string with a known format

Tags: python, performance, datetime

Let's say I have a string in the following format:

```
"YYYY mm dd"
```

What would be the fastest way to get it into a python date object? My first thought was:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('2018 01 12', "%Y %m %d").date()
datetime.date(2018, 1, 12)
```

However, I have about a million date-strings I need to convert, and was wondering if anyone had alternative methods that may be even faster, or benchmarks showing that the above would be the fastest.

Comment: Million in a single file? Perhaps you can try Pandas/Dask?

Comment: Why not read them into Pandas and use `pd.to_datetime()` on the entire column of strings?

Comment: @rahlf23 -- certainly a possibility...if that's the fastest way to do it.

Comment: That would certainly be my approach, with the limited scope of your question.

Comment: Do you keep all in memory or do you load them and write them back to e.g. a harddrive? If so, are you sure the the time will be spent mainly converting the data or perhaps the I/O will dominate anyway?